# How can I control how systemd assigns a service to a slice?

Tags: systemd, cgroup

I have been searching for a while for information about how services are assigned to slices - it seems to be a very elusive subject, or maybe I'm not asking the right questions. I've come across [How does systemd put sshd processes in slices?](https://serverfault.com/questions/968717/how-does-systemd-put-sshd-processes-in-slices), which asks a similar question, but doesn't get an answer.

So, to be more concrete: Say, I want to control how much memory mysqld can grab. I know that there is a service file: `mysql.service`, and there are slice files, like `system.slice` etc. With `systemd-cgls` I can see `mysql.service` is listed under `system.slice`, but if I wanted to create a new slice, say `db.slice`, and put the mysql service into that one, how would I do that? Or if that is not the right way, how about `system-db.slice`?

Comment: If you just want to limit the amount of RAM the service can use, there's no need to mess with slices.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That is not my main ambition - I want to know how to mess with slices and other units in general. In fact, now that I think about it, I would like to find an complete reference to all unit files and the options one can put inside them. What I have found so far has been incomplete and vague.

Comment: Eh? The systemd docs are thoroughly detailed and complete.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't looked closely enough, but I see eg. `Slice=system.slice` in one of my service files, but I can't find that option in the systemd docs

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#Slice=

Comment: I found it, but not listed with the other options. A bit sloppy, I think; it doesn't say explicitly where the option can be used, but searching around it seems to under `[Service]`

Comment: @j4nd3r53n `The resource control configuration options are configured in the [Slice], [Scope], [Service], [Socket], [Mount], or [Swap] sections, depending on the unit type.` Seems rather explicit to me.